# Are laws of reflection valid for irregular surfaces?

Tags: optics, reflection

The two laws of reflection are they applicable to both smooth surfaces and irregular surfaces or they are limited to just smooth surfaces.

Comment: yes , they are.

Comment: This is how I think of it, an irregular surface is a collection of infinitely many regular surfaces, therefore, the alws hold

Comment: welcome to PSE. Please take this tour https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour, to get to know how to  use this site

Answer (score 1):

If the irregularities are of the same order as the wavelength of the illumination then a substantial portion of the illumination will be scattered in many different directions rather than being reflected so the 'laws' will be only approximate. As irregularities tend to zero the 'laws' become more exact.